# other than statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

basically i have a username field in my website which i am trying to filter that user should insert characters only allowed in a username field.

any option is much appreciated but i'd prefer something like

```
 String allowedchars = "a-zA-Z0-9~`!@#()";
 if(username.value.contains other than allowedchars){

 } else {

 }
```

of course there is no kind of statement for other than but there could be some kind of function that could get the job done. 
thanks

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regexp to check if the whole input string contains but the specified allowed chars:

```
if (username.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9~`!@#\(\)]+$/)) {
    // username is valid
}
```

(My regex also assumes that the input must at least contains 1 char, otherwise you should replace `+` by `*`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex.test`:

```
var allowedchars = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9~`!@#()]+$");
var username = "myname";
if(allowedchars.test(username){
  // matches
} else {
  // doesn't match
}
```